# How can I put this margins on my document?

Tags: formatting, margins, templates, books

How can I put these margins on my document, alternating them between odd and even pages (as seen in the pictures)?. I've been looking for book templates, but the codes are too complicated and I don't know where I can start.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Run `texdoc tufte`.

Comment: See https://ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex (same as Fran) and https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/tufte.

Comment: You could also try https://github.com/fmarotta/kaobook or use https://www.ctan.org/pkg/sidenotes or https://www.ctan.org/pkg/snotez to set up your own document

Comment: Another option could be memoir class (`texdoc memoir`) it already has an environment for margin figures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example with `memoir` on how to achieve those margins and the figures in it[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\settypeblocksize{235mm}{120mm}{*}
\setlrmargins{17mm}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{25mm}{*}{*}
\setheadfoot{12pt}{8mm}
\setmarginnotes{5mm}{65mm}{2mm}
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{marginfigure}
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=63mm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Margin figure}
\end{marginfigure}
\lipsum[3-5]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the `kaobook` package, which has commands `\begin{marginfigure}`, `\marginnote{}` and more for making a professional-looking textbook.

You can open a template in Overleaf [here](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/kaobook).

[image]